# C# How Can I Sort A List without Generating Any Garbage at All (Unity3d)

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, unity-game-engine

The method used by List.Sort ends up using Array.Sort which generates 2 bytes of garbage even if you pass in an instance for IComparer. I need to sort many lists every frame in Unity3d so I need an algorithm that will not create a single byte of garbage if possible. Stack allocation for temporary variables should be fine.

[Unity Profiler Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvLWH.png)

```
if (comparer == null)
    comparer = (IComparer<T>)Comparer<T>.Default;
if (BinaryCompatibility.TargetsAtLeast_Desktop_V4_5)
    ArraySortHelper<T>.IntrospectiveSort(keys, index, length, comparer);
else
    ArraySortHelper<T>.DepthLimitedQuickSort(keys, index, length + index - 1, comparer, 32);
```

Comment: Are you sure that `Array.Sort` allocates? Can you identify what's being allocated?

Comment: I may not be garbage.  For error checking, the Net Library adds types to objects.

Comment: It would be better, if you explain why you are sorting many list in Update function. Maybe, people here can suggest you a better way to do this.

Comment: Atleast, according to the Unity profiler, it says that it's allocating 2 bytes whenever sort is called. The sorting is a requirement for my VR framework, that is unavoidable.

Comment: Uh, you can't allocate a 2-byte object in .NET -- the minimum object size is 12 bytes. So whatever you're seeing isn't an object allocation. I suspect you're misinterpreting what the profiler is telling you, whatever that is

Comment: @canton7 this is possible, but I'm going off what the profiler reports by dividing the reported allocation by the number of calls to the sort.

Comment: @canton7 In .Net, **short and ushort** can allocate 2 byte memory. [.Net Value Types](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/data-types-amp-type-conversions-in-c-sharp) and byte types can allocate only 1 byte

Comment: @SeLeCtRa They won't be heap allocated though: you can allocate 2 bytes for a short on the stack or inside another object, but if you allocate a short on the heap it gets boxed, and becomes a 12-byte allocation (it gains an 8-byte object header)

Comment: @canton7 I didn't know that fact. The site I linked didn't indicate that. But how we decide if I want to allocate, in heap or stack? Also, thanks for info.

Comment: @SeLeCtRa It seems more likely that it did a one-off allocation of `Comparer<T>.Default`. It doesn't matter if you don't use it -- just referring to it is probably enough for the runtime to kick off the static ctor for `Comparer<T>` (for your `T`), which will allocate the default comparer. If you do more or less numbers of calls, I'll bet the allocation size stays the same: try it! A single 112B allocation on your first sort isn't going to affect you

Comment: @SeLeCtRa Boxing and stack/heap allocation is a fairly basic topic in C#: I'm not going to hijack someone else's comments to explain it I'm afraid. There are good tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this library in this github [repo](https://github.com/jacksondunstan/iterator). I found this in bottom in this [article](https://www.jacksondunstan.com/articles/4840#:%7E:text=A%20handful%20of%20LINQ%20functions,ElementAtOrDefault%20%2C%20Single%20%2C%20and%20SingleOrDefault%20.&text=There%20are%20some%20exceptions%20that,small%20functions%20of%20minimal%20use.) which is about how LINQ affects GC and which LINQ function is safe to use on every frame. This library is written especially for unity and as author says this library is

> A no-GC version of C#'s IEnumerator and LINQ

There is sort method which implements quickSort algorithms and does not produce garbage.
To be honest I don't fully tested it yet, but as much as I used that it works finely.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look!

Comment: As far as I can tell, it implements InsertionSort only. It also offers a binary heap, albeit for some reason the author does not use it for sorting. But I did not see any quicksort?